# How to replace key label in an array

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I'm having this below array, where I need to update the key value as
From Apple fruit to Pizza shop, Orange fruit to Kfc shop, Banana fruit to Mcdonald shop, Mango fruit to fries shop if any one the value pair exceeds 15 characters, if it doesn't exceed 15 characters, it should remain the same response.

For instance in this Testing 3 has value that exceeds 15 characters

```
 [
        {
            "key": "Apple fruit",
            "value": "12123124344234234"
        },
        {
            "key": "Orange fruit",
            "value": "234352342332525"
        },
        {
            "key": "Banana fruit",
            "value": "235235235235235235235"
        },
        {
            "key": "Mango fruit",
            "value": "235325235235235"
        }
    ]
```

My code

```
    this.testItem.push({
      key: testlabel,
      value: testvale,
    });
    console.log(this.testItem);
```

this.testItem has the array of value I have mentioned above, any help ?

Comment: loop through array and check value length. when value length is more than 28 than change the value of key

Answer (score 1):

Your initial specs are a bit unclear, but regardless. Here is the code that will achieve what you are requesting:

```js
// Your array - don't add this 
this.testItem = [
        {
            "key": "Testing 1",
            "value": "66789/74657/37485/67543"
        },
        {
            "key": "Testing 2",
            "value": "66789/74657/37485/67543"
        },
        {
            "key": "Testing 3",
            "value": "3647586/456765/345654/36789876/76"
        },
        {
            "key": "Testing 4",
            "value": "66789/74657/37485/67543"
        }
    ];


// Add the code below to modify your array `this.testItem`
var hasValueExceeding28Chars = this.testItem.some(item => item.value.length > 28);

this.testItem = hasValueExceeding28Chars
  ? this.testItem.map(item => ({
      key: item.key.replace(/Testing/g, "Test"),
      value: item.value
    }))
  : this.testItem;

console.log(this.testItem);
```

Here we are:

1. Finding out whether any of the values exceed 28 characters;
2. If so, we are using [the map() function of Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to copy the initial into a new array and modifying all the keys accordingly;
3. If not, then we maintain the initial array.

Comment: I'm sorry I got where I went wrong but can you please update your answer, based on the array I have edited in the question.

Comment: @guru See if you can figure it out now

Comment: I'm quite new to this, that's why, if you could help that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
this.testItem =  [
        {
            "key": "Testing 1",
            "value": "66789/74657/37485/67543"
        },
        {
            "key": "Testing 2",
            "value": "66789/74657/37485/67543"
        },
        {
            "key": "Testing 3",
            "value": "3647586/456765/345654/36789876/76"
        },
        {
            "key": "Testing 4",
            "value": "66789/74657/37485/67543"
        }
    ];

const hasMoreThan28Chars = this.testItem.some(item => item.value.length > 28);

this.testItem = !hasMoreThan28Chars ? this.testItem : this.testItem.map((item) => 
    ({...item, key: item.key.replace("Testing", "Test")})
);

console.log(this.testItem)
```

Comment: This is only changing the value of which exceeds 28 charcters but my requirement is to change all the four labels if any of them exceed 28 characters

Comment: Your question wasn't particularly clear, however I've updated the code.

Comment: Can you look at my array and the solution which I'm expecting in the question, I guess your answer doesn't match that

Comment: now it matches.

Answer (score 0):

in place of hello write code to change value

```
testArray.forEach(test => { if(test.value.length > 28 )test.key='hello'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let testItem = [
        {
            "key": "Testing 1",
            "value": "3647586/456765/345654/36789876/76dwjdjwdn2"
        },
        {
            "key": "Testing 2",
            "value": "66789/74657/37485/67543"
        },
        {
            "key": "Testing 3",
            "value": "3647586/456765/345654/36789876/76"
        },
        {
            "key": "Testing 4",
            "value": "66789/74657/37485/67543"
        }
    ];

testItem = testItem.map(item => {
  if (item.value.length > 28) {
    const num = item.key.substring(item.key.length - 1)
    item.key = `Test ${num}`
  }
  return item
})

console.log(testItem);
```

answer:

```
[
  {
    key: 'Test 1',
    value: '3647586/456765/345654/36789876/76dwjdjwdn2'
  },
  { key: 'Testing 2', value: '66789/74657/37485/67543' },
  { key: 'Test 3', value: '3647586/456765/345654/36789876/76' },
  { key: 'Testing 4', value: '66789/74657/37485/67543' }
]
```

Comment: this is only replacing the the value label was has value more than 28 characters but I need to update the other label as well if any one of the value exceeds 28 characters

Comment: it will change the label of others also if the value's length exceeds 28 characters. Check my answer!